# objective c audio meter

Tags: objective-c, xcode, audio

Is it possible for xcode to have an audio level indicator?

I want to do something like this:

```
if (audioLevel = 100) {
}
```

or something similar...

Any ideas?? Example code please?

I'm VERY new to objective c so the more explaining the beter! :D

Comment: Xcode is just an IDE - you're probably talking about Cocoa (Mac OS X) or CocoaTouch (iPhone, iPad, etc) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a very straightforward API to do this.  You need to use the low level [AudioToolbox.framework](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CAAudioTooboxRef/index.html).

Luckily, others have already solved this problem for you.  Here's some code I simplified slightly to be straight C functions, from [CocoaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?SoundVolume).  You need to link to the AudioToolbox to compile this code ([see here for documentation on how to do so](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002257-BAJJBBHJ)).

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>

AudioDeviceID getDefaultOutputDeviceID()
{
    AudioDeviceID outputDeviceID = kAudioObjectUnknown;

    // get output device device
    OSStatus status = noErr;
    AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAOPA;
    propertyAOPA.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
    propertyAOPA.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;
    propertyAOPA.mSelector = kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice;

    if (!AudioHardwareServiceHasProperty(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &propertyAOPA))
    {
        printf("Cannot find default output device!");
        return outputDeviceID;
    }

    status = AudioHardwareServiceGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &propertyAOPA, 0, NULL, (UInt32[]){sizeof(AudioDeviceID)}, &outputDeviceID);

    if (status != 0) 
    {
        printf("Cannot find default output device!");
    }
    return outputDeviceID;
}

float getVolume () 
{
    Float32 outputVolume;

    OSStatus status = noErr;
    AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAOPA;
    propertyAOPA.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;
    propertyAOPA.mSelector = kAudioHardwareServiceDeviceProperty_VirtualMasterVolume;
    propertyAOPA.mScope = kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput;

    AudioDeviceID outputDeviceID = getDefaultOutputDeviceID();

    if (outputDeviceID == kAudioObjectUnknown)
    {
        printf("Unknown device");
        return 0.0;
    }

    if (!AudioHardwareServiceHasProperty(outputDeviceID, &propertyAOPA))
    {
        printf("No volume returned for device 0x%0x", outputDeviceID);
        return 0.0;
    }

    status = AudioHardwareServiceGetPropertyData(outputDeviceID, &propertyAOPA, 0, NULL, (UInt32[]){sizeof(Float32)}, &outputVolume);

    if (status)
    {
        printf("No volume returned for device 0x%0x", outputDeviceID);
        return 0.0;
    }

    if (outputVolume < 0.0 || outputVolume > 1.0) return 0.0;

    return outputVolume;
}

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("%f", getVolume());
    return 0;
}
```

Note that there's also a setVolume function there, too.

Comment: @Elijah: Glad to be of help. If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox. :)