# Core Audio and retrieving data sources from a audio device

Tags: cocoa, core-audio, osx-leopard

I've managed to get a list of data sources from an audio device by using `AudioObjectPropertyAddress` and `AudioObjectGetPropertyData()`.

Is it possible to get the volume of a data source without having to do a set?
The only way I can get the volume of a data source would be:

1. set the data source id that I'm interested in as the devices's current data source
2. get the volume of the device.

This is quite annoying as I would have to listen for a call back for the set of data source to be complete before I can query for the volume, and this is trouble some as I would like to query a few data sources that are on this device.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you need to use the you need to use the low level [AudioToolbox.framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiotoolbox) to accomplish this. This [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170002/objective-c-audio-meter) has some sample code that lets you take the deviceID and get the volume for the specific device and it does not use callbacks.